# Verify the return json reponse is not more than one in POSTMAN assert

Tags: node.js, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have the returned response in the POSTMAN:

```
{
    "first_name": "Abc",
    "last_name": "dbc",
    "email": "abc@example.com",
    "id": 46
}
```

How can i verify the returned result json length is not more than one, this is what i have tried:

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.test('Has data and only returns 1 result', function() {
  pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property('first_name');
  pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property('last_name');
  pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property('email');
  pm.expect(jsonData.length).to.equal(1);

});
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Has data and only returns 1 result | AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 1
```

Comment: Objects do not have a length property only arrays.  What exactly are you trying to check?  It looks like its returning an object and not an array if the first 3 checks are passing.

Comment: yes other pass. What should i test then?

Comment: It's not very clear what it is you're asking or trying to test

Comment: I am trying to verify it only returns one json as above. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single Json object doesn't have a length property so you can't do it that way. One suggestion would be for you to push the Json object into an array and then you could verify the length:

```
var json = pm.response.json();
var data = [];
data.push(json);

tests["Test length of array"] = data === 4;
```

I didn't actually test this code but I think it should work, or you can play around with the idea.